# Suppress QXmlSchemaValidator Application Output Error Messages

Tags: qt, xsd-validation, verify, suppress

I am using `QXmlSchemaValidator` to validate my `xml` against different `xsds`.
My code is as follows:

```
bool MyClass::verify(QByteArray message)
{    
   bool successfulValidated = false;
   for(QByteArray& xsd: _xsds)
   {
       QXmlSchema schema;
       schema.load(xsd);
       if(!schema.isValid())
           throw Exception("schema not valid");
       QXmlSchemaValidator msgValidator(schema);        
       if(msgValidator.validate(message))
       {
           successfulValidated = true;
           break;
       }
   }
   return successfulValidated;
}
```

If `msgValidator.validate(message)` is `false` I get and application output like

Error XSDError in file:///MyApplication.exe, at line 1, column 47: No definition for element MyXMLElement available.

I do not want these application output messages as they clutter my output window. Is there any way that I can either suppress these messages or handle them myself?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same problem:

Just add your own `MessageHandler` to the `QXmlSchema` as described in [this Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254592/qt-xml-validation-errorhandling).